Laravel email template code not refreshing when using Notification and laravel scheduler
I am using the laravel scheduler to send emails to the users when their account is being created here is my MailBatch class code:
class MailBatch extends Command
{
/**
 * The name and signature of the console command.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $signature = 'app:mail-batch';

/**
 * The console command description.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $description = 'send mail in pending mode';

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 */
public function handle()
{
    $mailToSend = Mail::where('status', 'pending')->take('50')->orderBy('created_at')->get();

    $emailLists = [];


    foreach ($mailToSend as $mail) {
        $emailBody = json_decode($mail->content);

        // $sendEmail = new GraphApiController();

        $statusSend = 'send';

        $recipients = $emailBody->message->toRecipients;
        $recipientsArray = [];
        $ccArray = [];
        $bccArray = [];

        foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {
            $recipientsArray[] = $recipient->emailAddress->address;
            if (isset($recipient->emailAddress->cc)) {
                $ccArray[] = $recipient->emailAddress->cc;
            }

            if(isset($recipient->emailAddress->bcc)) {
                $bccArray[] = $recipient->emailAddress->bcc;
            }

        }

        $replyTo = null;
        if(isset($emailBody->message->replyTo)) {
            $replyTo = $emailBody->message->replyTo;
        }


        try {
            $emailLists[] = Mailer::send(new NotifyUsers(
                $recipientsArray,
                $emailBody->message->subject,
                $emailBody->message->body->content,
                $ccArray,
                $bccArray,
                $replyTo
            ));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $statusSend = 'error';
            $emailLists[] = $e->getMessage();
        }

        $mail->status = $statusSend;
        $mail->send_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
        $mail->save();
    }
}

}
In My NotifyUsers class I am using am using NotifyUsers template like:
[AllowDynamicProperties] class NotifyUsers extends Mailable
{
use Queueable, SerializesModels;

public array $receivers;
public array $ccs;
public array $bccs;
public string $messageSubject;
public string $emailBody;
/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 */
public function __construct($receivers, $messageSubject, $emailBody, $ccs = [], $bccs = [], $replyTo = null)
{
    $this->receivers = $receivers;
    $this->ccs = $ccs;
    $this->bccs = $bccs;
    $this->messageSubject = $messageSubject;
    $this->emailBody = $emailBody;
    $this->replyToUser = $replyTo;

}

/**
 * Get the message envelope.
 */
public function envelope(): Envelope
{
    return new Envelope(
        from: new Address(Config::get('constants.support_email'), Config::get('constants.support_name')),
        to: $this->receivers,
        cc: $this->ccs,
        bcc: $this->bccs,
        replyTo: $this->replyToUser,
        subject: $this->messageSubject,
    );
}

/**
 * Get the message content definition.
 */
public function content(): Content
{
    return new Content(
        view: 'email.notifyUsers',
    );
}

/**
 * Get the attachments for the message.
 *
 * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Attachment>
 */
public function attachments(): array
{

    $files= File::allFiles(public_path('logo'));
    $latestFile = collect($files)->sortByDesc(function ($file) {
        return $file->getMTime();
    })->first();

    $totalPath =  public_path('logo').'/'.$latestFile->getFileName();
    return [
        Attachment::fromPath($totalPath)
    ];
}

}
Here is the code for the notifyusers template.
@extends('email.layout')

@section("content")
   {!! $emailBody !!}
@endsection

When I make changes in my layout and try using the scheduler the contents of the layout always stay the same
I have used the use commands like php optimze:clear and php view:clear but my layout never seems to change.

clear your cache and then check. Usually servers do cache the pages and dont update on change.

Is this a queued job? If yes, each time you make a change in your Mailable class, you need to restart your queue. You can read more about it here: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/queues#queue-workers-and-deployment

@zlatan I am using a scheduler not a queue, do I need to restart the scheduler? Is it the same command as php schedule:restart.
